# Database replication in Postgresql using triggers

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a difficult time finding if PostgreSQL can insert/update/delete tables across different databases. 
Here is what i want to perform:
I have two databases: 
database_a and database_b
database_a contains a table table_a
database_b contains a table table_a 
I want to update table_a in database_b with changes made at table_a in database_a.
So table_a in database_b will always contain same data as table_a in database_a. In PostgreSQL by using triggers

Comment: Use foreign tables

Comment: +1 If you have to do a lot of heavy joining via foreign tables, consider keeping the data in a single database. Schemas allow excellent access protection.

Comment: But i have to do the replication between those databases, iam facing the problem after using of fdw it is creating foreign tables.

Comment: Using a foreign table the data only exists once, you don't have to replicate it. The database is managing access to the data for you.

Comment: After closing the main server i'am unable to access the data in secondary server